# Percentage-complete calculation: display as integer if whole number, otherwise display fractional number

Tags: python, math, integer, decimal

Given this code ([saved here as a gist](https://gist.github.com/hughlilly/7119ee75393234b9726703cd1098498b)):

```py
import glob

num_files = len(glob.glob('*.jpg'))
if num_files > 0:
    print("Found {0} JPEG files".format(num_files))
    jpeg_files = glob.iglob('*.jpg')
    for count, filename in enumerate(jpeg_files, start=1):
        print("----\n")
        percent_complete = int((count * 100) / num_files)
        print("File: {0} ({1} of {2}; {3}%).".format(
               filename, count, num_files, percent_complete))
        if count == num_files:
            print("Working on {0}...".format(filename))
            # do stuff
            print("That was the last file.\n")
        else:
            print("Working on {0}...\n".format(filename))
            # do stuff
else:
    print("No .jpg files in current directory. Exiting.")
    pass
```

I have two main questions:

1. Is there a better way to structure the first part, where I run `glob` in order to get the number of files? Is there some way to run the iterator only if its count is non-zero?
2. Because I've done `(count * 100)`, the print statement will only ever show "5%" or "25", never "25.5%" or "39.6%". How can I get `percent_complete` to display as a fraction (i.e. "32.5%") only if the percentage is a whole number? (i.e. I don't want "25.0" displayed.)

Thank you,
Hugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove int() and add this:

```
...
percent_complete = (count * 100) / num_files
if percent_complete % 1 == 0:
    percent_complete = int(percent_complete)
print...
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by making a function to determine if the percentage is an integer value, and return the value to two decimal places if not:

```py
import glob

def two_decimals(number: float):
    """Return passed number to two decimal places if not an integer,
    otherwise return number as an integer."""
    if (number - int(number) != 0):
        return "%.2f" % number
    else:
        return "%d" % number

num_files = len(glob.glob('*.jpg'))

if num_files > 0:
    
    print("Found {0} JPEG files".format(num_files))
    jpeg_files = glob.iglob('*.jpg')

    for count, filename in enumerate(jpeg_files, start=1):
        percent_complete = ((count * 100) / num_files)
        print("File: {0} ({1} of {2}; {3}%).".format(
               filename,
               count,
               num_files, 
               two_decimals(percent_complete)))
        if count == num_files:
            print("Working on {0}...".format(filename))
            # do stuff
            print("That was the last file.\n")
        else:
            print("Working on {0}...\n".format(filename))
            # do stuff
else:
    print("No .jpg files in current directory. Exiting.")
    pass
```